# Where should I ask my graph-theoretic questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have several questions related to graph theory (i.e. existence / properties of certain graphs). Is it better to ask them here in math.SE, or in cs.SE? Both fields study graph theory in depth.

Comment: I would look at the  questions posted under http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory and under http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory , then post where they look more similar to mine.

Comment: Unless you are asking about complexity of graph algorithms, my guess is you'd be better off under Math.SE.

Comment: There is also an [area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63050/graph-theory) for a separate site Graph Theory. However, I would be surprised if this proposal ever get at least to beta.